# HLookup() with date: Already tried CLng()

Tags: excel, vba, date

the following is my code. Basically I want to find the row value of a cell in another workbook ("x" in here), with matching dates. The code is running but it isn't returning the value.

`Cells(2,10)` is a date (written as dic-13), and the first row of `Range("B8:J9")` is a `Range` of date as ( "dic-11", "dic-12", "dic-13" etc...)

```
Sub BuscarDatos()
Dim y As Workbook
Dim x As Workbook

Set y = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set x = Application.Workbooks.Open("G:\Estudios\Biblioteca\Mercado Accionario _ 
Chileno\InsertarEmpresa.xlsm")

y.Sheets("Información Financiera").Cells(Range("J3").Row, Range("J3").Column) = _
Application.HLookup(CLng(Cells(2, 10)), _
x.Sheets("Cencosud").Range("B8:J9"), 2, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't qualify `Cells(2, 10)` Edit: also `Cells(Range("J3").Row, Range("J3").Column)` is very...wordy?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the wordy code, I'm learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Sub BuscarDatos()
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim x As Workbook
    Set y = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set x = Application.Workbooks.Open("G:\Estudios\Biblioteca\Mercado Accionario Chileno\InsertarEmpresa.xlsm")
    'modified line
    y.Sheets("Información Financiera").Cells(Range("J3").Row, Range("J3").Column) = Application.HLookup(y.Sheets("Información Financiera").Cells(2, 10), x.Sheets("Cencosud").Range("B8:J9"), 2, False) 'modified line
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Worked well !

Comment: please mark it as solution if you are satisfy with the code